# OpenCL for Intel CPU and Nvidia GPU simultaneously

Tags: opencl, intel, nvidia

I am trying to get started with some OpenCL coding.

I've installed the NVidia CUDA OpenCL on my computer and have managed to build a simple "Hello World!" application using Visual Studio 2017.

I have also installed the Intel OpenCL SDK (installation warned me that I needed to update my OpenCL drivers but the Intel update manager was telling me that everything was up to date, so I'm not sure whether this could be an issue).

Now whenever I query the OpenCL platforms on my PC lie so:

```
std::vector< cl::Platform > platformList;
cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
```

I only get back my nVidia openCL platform, with my GPU as the only device. I am not getting anything back for my CPU.

Can anyone help? Is it possible to perform both CPU and GPU OpenCL computations in the same project (In different OpenCL contexts? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It seems you are linking OpenCL.dll from nVidia, could that be the reason? Pls try to link dll from Intel.

Comment: What CPU model do you have?

Comment: CPU is a i7-7700k. I tried using Intel's includes and OpenCL.lib from intels sdk, and only get the GPU still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that Intel GPU driver was not installed properly. You can install a CPU-only package instead: 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_CPU_runtime